# esy-osmfilter missing modules errors

Tags: python-3.x, osmfilter

Perhaps I don't understand, but I am trying to use esy-osmfilter, and I clearly don't understand what I am missing.
Using the documentation [here](https://dlr-ve-esy.gitlab.io/esy-osmfilter/usage.html)... I ran the sample.py, and there is no module run_filter. It's nowhere on my computer.

Can someone please help me with using this tool.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing: **from esy.osmfilter import run_filter**

but this should be already in your [sample.py](https://gitlab.com/dlr-ve-esy/esy-osmfilter/-/blob/master/sample.py) file.
Or did you miss: pip install esy-osmfilter

Cheers Adam

Comment: As you said, the sample file has the line from esy.osmfilter import run_filter. I just changed it to from build.lib.esy.osmfilter import run_filter, to find the files in the build directory.
I had alread installed the esy-osmfilter package through pip install, as was instructed in the tutorial.
I don't know what the problem could have been, but it worked as it should have from the start.
I am now trying to figure out what was preventing it from working, since the only thing I can remember doing was removing a plugin from QGIS which was causing a python script error.
Thanks for responding.